# Measure shortest distance from a point to a line in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3

I am fairly new to QGIS and I have been using it to determine the shortest distance between multiple points using a network of roads.  After seeing the results, I see that there is usually a gap between the origin point and the network (this happens with the destination points as well).  In some cases the shortest path cannot be determined is that gap is too large, but I do not know what is considered as "too large".
So my question is, is there a way to define a maximum allowable distance between a point and a line to determine a shortest path? (ie. If there is not a road within at least 200 meters from the origin then it is not possible to determine a shortest path between two points) [image: Shortest distance between point 480 and 607]

Comment: did you consider making a buffer on the roads layer and filter out points outside that buffer?

Comment: I haven't.  I was thinking about creating a buffer around the points but I do not know where is that option in QGIS 3.

Comment: The simple way of finding anything on qgis is looking the toolbox, under processes menu. https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing/toolbox.html